# column (column_name) of relation (table_name) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

The parameters are identical to the columns of the reference table, but still accuse that such a column does not exist in this table.

[image: See the picture]

Comment: What schema is this table in? What is the schema search path?